# Is there a security flaw in adding the production security_key_base key directly in secrets.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm deploying a rails 4.2 app and realise I need to set a production `secret_key_base` key

config/secrets.yml

```
# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

It wants me to set the key in an environment variable named `SECRET_KEY_BASE`. Now if i don't share this file on any git repo is there any security flaw in just setting the `secret_key_base` directly in the secrets.yml file? How would a person be able to access this file and get the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is less secure to add directly because the attack area is increased.  Meaning there are more ways that someone can get the data from your rails server.

If you add this directly, someone would need to be able to read the file system of your rails server.  This could be through a directory traversal attack of some sort where they are able to see the contents of your file system.

If you only add them to ENV and use secrets.yml in that way, they would have to be able to read the ENV of the user running the rails process.  Normally that is either root or another privileged user account that you grant access to spawn processes to serve requests to rails.  To do this requires them to completely take over that user process, which is generally more difficult to do.

Comment: Thanks thats what I wanted to know